# Java : Creating a String class : ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, data-structures, entity-relationship, indexoutofboundsexception

Note : Please don't say to use String class methods as here I am creating all String method on my own.

Objective : Consider two string prince and soni. I want  **computeConcate**   method to ask for position ( Say 4 is entered ) and then obtain string from first name starting from beginning till 4th position and concate it with the last name viz soni. Hence I got prinsoni

Error : ArrayIndexOutOfBondsException on line labled as Error within computeConcate() method

Reason of the error : The string so obtained ( viz concatenation of first and last name can be of atmost length of first + last name )

So I created String

```
char []firstSubString;
    firstSubString = new char[so.computeLength(firstName) + so.computeLength(lastName)];
```

Its length right now is as I though sum of first and last name but after this method computeSubstring() it changes to of length of first name.

What I want?

> Can you provide me a way so that computeSubstring doesn't end up
>   changing lenght of firstSubString.

```
/**
 * Take two strings 
 * Run a loop pause when counter is encountered
 * Now use + to concatenate them
 **/
@Override
public char[] computeConcatenation(char[] firstName, char[] lastName, int pos ) {
    StringClass so = new StringClass();
    Boolean flag = false;
    char []firstSubString;
    firstSubString = new char[so.computeLength(firstName) + so.computeLength(lastName)];

    System.out.println( firstSubString.length ); // O/p is 10 ( length of                                            //                                                  first name + last name

    firstSubString = so.computeSubstring(firstName, pos);

    System.out.println( firstSubString.length );   // o/p is 6. length of                         //                                                   first name

    int len = so.computeLength(firstSubString);

    // To find pos
    for(int i = 0; i < so.computeLength(lastName); i++){

        // ArrayIndexOfOfBondsException on this line
Error : firstSubString[len + i] = lastName[i]; 
    } 
    return firstSubString;
}



Here is the code for substring method

/**
 * Traverse the string till pos. Store this string into a new string
 */
@Override
public  char[]  computeSubstring(char[] name, int pos) {
    StringClass so = new StringClass();
    char []newName;
    newName = new char[so.computeLength(name)];



        for(int i = 0; i < so.computeLength(name); i++){
        if( i == pos) break;
        newName[i] = name[i];
    }
    return newName;
}
```

Comment: You should write a utility/testing method that takes your arg and dumps them to standard out. Just writing this method will probably show you where the error is.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta Codereview is for **working code only**. Broken code is off-topic there.

Comment: @jdv Writing a testing method is later topic once I figure out  this change in length problem, I had explained.

The question right now is that why the hell firstSubString  length got changed after computeSubString method and how can I prevent it from changing.

Comment: Anyone, here to help me??

Comment: @PrinceSoni, if you write the test method/debug method to dump the contents of the byte arrays, you will find your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it changes because you are overwriting `firstSubString` here:

```
firstSubString = so.computeSubstring(firstName, pos);
```

What you want to do; however, is copy the result of `computeString` *into* the first part of `firstSubString`. You can do this rather simply with [System.arraycopy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

```
char[] result = so.computeSubstring(firstName, pos);
System.arraycopy(result, 0, firstSubstring, 0, result.length);
```

This will copy the result into the front of the firstSubstring. This will not alter its length at all.

Comment: Thanks bro. Apologies for very untidy code though :D. Old Days !!